# How Geth and Parity knows the global gas limit?

Tags: gas-limit

As said in Péter Szilágyi post [DAO Wars: Your voice on the soft-fork dilemma](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/06/24/dao-wars-youre-voice-soft-fork-dilemma/):

> Miners supporting the DAO soft-fork can do so by starting Geth 1.4.8
>   with --dao-soft-fork. This will cause the block gas limits to be
>   lowered towards Pi million until the deciding block 1800000 (approx. 6
>   days from now) is reached. If the gas limit of this block is below or
>   equal 4M, the soft-fork goes into effect and (all updating) miners
>   will start blocking DAO transactions that release funds.

How does the Geth (or Parity) client knows the current global network gas limit ? I can't see any explorer that shows it except https://ethstats.net/ that only shows some voluntary nodes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The block `gasLimit` is in each block.  Example:

> eth.getBlock(1500000)

```
{
  difficulty: 34982465665323,
  extraData: "0xd783010305844765746887676f312e352e31856c696e7578",
  gasLimit: 4712388,
  ...
}
```

Comment: "Is in each block" was the key. I was looking for a global data... thanks.